# Using overflow in percentage height container

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page that takes up the full screen height (without scroll bars), yet has a scrollable container inside it. I have tried using percentage heights, but each time the percentages don't work when they are used inside each other.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. I have tried many other versions, but none of them work.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="pageheader">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Section header</h2>
            <p>Header text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="overflower">
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#overflower {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RDSx9/

The `overflower` div should be scrollable, while the rest of the page remains static, taking up the whole height of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested percentage heights has long been a problem with CSS 2. Thankfully, CSS 3 brings a valuable tool that can be used to solve this problem (and similar problems) once and for all: flexboxes.

The idea is simple: flexboxes allow the developer to define how a section can grow or shrink depending on the space available for it, which in this case can be used to define that the `overflower` div should get as much space as it can inside its parent, which is set to take up as much space as it can inside its parent... all the way up to `body` (which is set to take up the whole screen height).

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="pagecontainer">
    <div id="pageheader">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Section header</h2>
            <p>Header text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="overflower">
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#pagecontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
#pageheader {
    flex: none;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: auto;
    background: green;
}
#header {
    flex: none;
}
#overflower {
    overflow: auto;
    flex: auto;
    background: blue;
}
```

Unforunately jsfiddle does some strange things when it comes to messing with `body`, so the only way to test this is to make a separate HTML file. Notice the inclusion of a `div id="pagecontainer` - this is needed to apply the `display: flex`. If you stack more elements between the `overflow` div and `body`, make sure to apply the 3 flex properties to each one!